# How to Remove Special Character in JSON code output in html using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, json

**What I need? I need in the Output:**

kind: pagespeedonline#result
id:http://ipv4.google.com/sorry/index?continue=http://google.com/&q=EgRC-V0oGNT5k9AFIhkA8aeDS7H3-G0PVLS9rlyqHTECJPpug6NeMgFy

responseCode: 503

title: http://google.com/

score: 98

pageStats: 
numberResources: 10

numberHosts: 4

totalRequestBytes: 964

numberStaticResources: 6

htmlResponseBytes: 33184

cssResponseBytes: 140515

imageResponseBytes: 2701

javascriptResponseBytes: 238456

otherResponseBytes:3511

numberJsResources: 4

numberCssResources: 1

**What are the issued? Currently, The output are like this,**

```
 "kind": "pagespeedonline#result",
 "id": "http://ipv4.google.com/sorry/index?continue=http://google.com/&q=EgRC-V0oGNT5k9AFIhkA8aeDS7H3-G0PVLS9rlyqHTECJPpug6NeMgFy",
 "responseCode": 503,
 "title": "http://google.com/",
 "score": 98,
 "pageStats": {
  "numberResources": 10,
  "numberHosts": 4,
  "totalRequestBytes": "964",
  "numberStaticResources": 6,
  "htmlResponseBytes": "33184",
  "cssResponseBytes": "140515",
  "imageResponseBytes": "2701",
  "javascriptResponseBytes": "238456",
  "otherResponseBytes": "3511",
  "numberJsResources": 4,
  "numberCssResources": 1
 },
 "formattedResults": {
  "locale": "en_US",
  "ruleResults": {
   "AvoidLandingPageRedirects": {
    "localizedRuleName": "Avoid landing page redirects",
    "ruleImpact": 0.0,
    "urlBlocks": [
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "Your page has no redirects. Learn more about avoiding landing page redirects.",
       "args": [
        {
         "type": "HYPERLINK",
         "value": "https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/AvoidRedirects"
        }
       ]
      }
     }
    ]
   },
```

What i tried?

```
var specialChars = "!@#$^&%*()+=-[]\/{}|:<>?,.";
for (var i = 0; i < specialChars.length; i++) {
    stringToReplace = stringToReplace .replace(new RegExp("\\" + specialChars[i], 'gi'), '');
}
```

But nothing happen.

Here is the file:

```js
function clicked() {
  document.getElementById("data").innerHTML =
    "Fethching Score and Ranking <br>loading...";

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
  if (url == "") {
    alert("Please enter URL");
    return;
  }
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(
    "GET",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?screenshot=false&strategy=mobile&url=" +
      encodeURIComponent(url)
  );
  
  xhr.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
  };
  xhr.send();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter URL with http:// or https://" id="url" class="form-control"/>
<p>with <code>http</code> or <code>https</code></p>
<input type="button" value=" ENTER " onclick="clicked();"/>

 <pre id="data"></pre> <!--output json here-->
```

I think i have some mistake in where to put the code to remove the special character on the output.

Comment: Codepen demo has nothing to do with question

Comment: what does that have to do with string replacing? Just a waste of time looking at demos that are meaningless

Comment: @charlietfl - I edited my Question I hope this will help now. THanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you not just use

```
.replace(/[!@#$^&%*()+=[\]/{}|:<>?,.\\-]/g, '')
```

This would replace all the invalid characters at once.

```js
let str = '<pre> --all special character @#$%&*()\\??><{}[]</pre>'

str = str.replace(/[!@#$^&%*()+=[\]\/{}|:<>?,.\\-]/g, '')

console.log(str)
```

Comment: @damikongaccontdito instead of saying *"it's still not working"*, how about you provide a sample input string? Clearly from my answer snippet you can see that all the required characters are removed from the string

Comment: @damikongaccontdito so rather than actually provide the required information, you've decided to just link to your useless example again?

Comment: @damikongaccontdito it would be better if you provided an example of the strings in their original format and then an example of how you'd like them to appear after removing characters.

Comment: @ Phil i think this okay now.. i edited again the Question

Answer (score 1):

It is what you want, isn't it?

```js
function clicked() {
  document.getElementById("data").innerHTML =
    "Fethching Score and Ranking <br>loading...";

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
  if (url == "") {
    alert("Please enter URL");
    return;
  }
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(
    "GET",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?screenshot=false&strategy=mobile&url=" +
      encodeURIComponent(url)
  );
  
  xhr.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = xhr.responseText.replace(/[!@#$^&%*()+=[\]\/{}|:<>?,.\\-]/g, '');;
  };
  xhr.send();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter URL with http:// or https://" id="url" class="form-control"/>
<p>with <code>http</code> or <code>https</code></p>
<input type="button" value=" ENTER " onclick="clicked();"/>

 <pre id="data"></pre> <!--output json here-->
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I edited my question... i hope this will help now. Still too many special character on my output...

Comment: `white-space: pre-line;` its clean now only the line height any suggestion

Comment: Is there anyway to remove the empty-line/space? Thanks